# Vertical line through all plots in R

Tags: r

I have got this graph below using this code for an example of one plot:

```
varia_plot <- df_sum %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100) %>%
  ggscatter(x = "VE", y = "absVO2", color = "group", size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) +
  geom_vline(aes(colour = c("red", "blue")), xintercept = c(VT1PPO_CAD, VT1PPO_healthy), linetype="solid") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = percentPPO), linetype="dashed") +
  annotate("text", x=VT1PPO_CAD-2, y=1,   ##or bp_CAD if we use absVO2%
           label=paste0("VT1: ", round(VT1PPO_CAD, 0), "%"), angle=90, size = 10) + ##or bp_CAD if we use absVO2%
  annotate("text", x=VT1PPO_healthy-2, y=1,   ##or bp_CAD if we use absVO2%
           label=paste0("VT1: ", round(VT1PPO_healthy, 0), "%"), angle=90, size = 10) + ##or bp_CAD if we use absVO2%
  xlab("VE (L/min)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (L/min)"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill ="white", colour = "white"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.text = element_blank()
  )
```

Then, I combine all plots created using this code:

```
plot <- ggarrange(variaVO2,
                  variaVE,
                  variaVO2fVE,
                  variaVCO2,
                  variaBF,
                  variaVCO2fVE,
                  variaHR,
                  variaVT,
                  variaVEVO2,
                  variaRER,
                  variaRmec,
                  variaVEVCO2,
                  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"),
                  ncol = 3, nrow = 4)
```

It is not very reader friendly at the moment. I would like to put a single vertical line for `VT1 58%` and `VT1 68%` going through all plots, instead of being in each plot.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It would probably look better to remove the annotations for the vertical lines.  Describe them in the plot title or subtitle.  Perhaps remove the x and y axis labels from the subplots.  The y axis labels could be moved to facet labels.  Put the x axis label once at the bottom.

Comment: Adding `align="hv"` to `ggarrange()` might help align all the charts.

Comment: Thank you both. There are 2 vertical solid lines in each graph for 58% and 68% of `Percentage power`. Do you know how I can make only 2 solid lines going through all plots (from the top to the buttom) ?